# Anylogic Simulation help - multiple sources

Tags: anylogic, agent

I'm new to Anylogic simulation. Just after some advise on building my simulation.

I'm trying to build a simulation that models 6 different types of cars which need their engine, tries, breaks, etc serviced. I have all this information table showing the distribution of the arrival of each type of car, the repair time, etc

What I'm after is, how do I enter multiple variables in my simulation that each have different parameters. I.e. there are 6 different type of cars but there's dozens of cars that come in every week, how do I model the source for my simulation.

I tried using different sources, but that didn't work because each type of car needs different type of service. I.e. not every car needs it's engine serviced, etc

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Welcome again, happy to help